# Azure test result add - testCaseTitle empty

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using this documentation to try to publish some test:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#examples

This is the body of my request. The results are coming in, but the `testCaseTitle` is missing.

Is this a BUG or am I missing something?

```json
[
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "testPlan": "7847",
    "priority": 1,
    "outcome": "Passed",
    "computerName": "my PC",
    "errorMessage": "error test",
    "durationInMs": 35660
  },
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "priority": 2,
    "outcome": "Failed",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

See attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this case: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/rest-api-to-post-steps-and-steps-result-of-test-ca/602005 helpful to your issue?

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT - no not quite. I do not see anything related between the two, except they both use the DevOps Test Rest API